# Java - Recursively count occurrences of a word in a List

Tags: java, recursion

looking for a hand with some recursion, I know it's a simple issue somewhere exiting but not sure how/where!

Here's my recursive method:

```
public static int getNumAppearances(myList<String> l, String word)
{
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String search = word;

    if(index > l.my_get_length()-1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(l.my_get_element(index).equals(search))
    {
        count++;
        index++;
    }

    return count + getNumAppearances(l, word);
}
```

Cheers!

Edit, myList Class:

```
public interface myList<T> {

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create an empty MyList: create_empty
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    //public myList create_empty(); --> Java does not support constructors in interfaces

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Basic Operation --> Get number of elements in MyList: my_get_length
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------   
    public int my_get_length();

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Basic Operation --> Get element at of MyList at a concrete position: my_get_element
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    public T my_get_element(int index) throws myException;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Basic Operation --> Add element to MyList at a concrete position: my_add_element 
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void my_add_element(int index, T element) throws myException;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Basic Operation --> Remove element of MyList at a concrete position: my_remove_element 
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------   
    public void my_remove_element(int index) throws myException;

}
```

I've realised you ideally need an index being passed to the method but unfortunately that's not the way he has it set up!

Comment: please specify the problem you're facing.

Comment: There isn't a reason to do this recursively. Just loop through your list and check for the word.

Comment: @AndyB quite likely it's a homework assignment designed to teach recursion - so a more sensible approach isn't allowed

Comment: Seeing the code for the `myList` class (which I assume is a custom list implementation) would also help.

Comment: It is an assignment alright, the only part which doesn't make sense to me due to not being able to pass an Index as a Parameter! Code added for myList, cheers.

Comment: you can check the last word, determine if it is equal, then recursively call your function with a new list, where the word you just checked, has been removed. Once the list is empty, you have seen all words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count in your function by modifying the list as such:

```
public class RecursiveListWordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(count(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "a", "b", "c"), "d"));
    }

    public static final int count(List<String> list, String word) {
        if(list.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(list.get(0).equals(word)) {
            return 1 + count(list.subList(1, list.size()), word);
        } else {
            return 0 + count(list.subList(1, list.size()), word);
        }

    }
}
```

On each call, I check if the list is empty, if `true` I will return 0 (as an empty list surely has no word in it that may be equal).

The next call then would add a sublist, removing the word I just checked.

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: unfortunately I cannot modify the list, it must stay as it!

Comment: The above code does not modify your original list. It creates a copy of your list and passes it on. Once the recursive function returns, your list will still have the same items in the same order and be unmodified. There is no other way (apart from counting the indexes as a field rather than a local variable but that would be a terrible solution :))

Comment: I only have those 4 methods to use though, my_get_length(), my_remove_element(), my_get_element() and my_add_element., can't use .subList etc

Comment: Then use my_remove_element? I think you need to clarify your question or post the entire assignment as this seems like key points are missing. You mention you can not modify the list, but then tell me you may call my_remove_element. By using remove, instead of creating a sublist, you achieve the same result, however you will end up with an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're utilising the `index` variable incorrectly because you're *always* checking the same `index` each time the method calls itself, I would recommend using the `index` as a parameter to the method. Also instead of keeping a `count` variable, we can just add `1` to the result each time we find a match.

```
public static int getNumAppearances(List<String> list, String word, int index)
{      if(list == null || list.size() == 0 || index < 0) return -1; // you can throw an exception instead if you deem it necessary.
       if(index > list.size() - 1) return 0;
       else if(list.get(index).equals(word)) return 1 + getNumAppearances(list, word, index + 1);
       return getNumAppearances(list, word, index + 1);
}
```

*note* - when calling the method, make sure you pass `0` as the argument to the `index` parameter, as this approach examines the list from the start to the end.

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately I cannot change the method he wants us to use so I cannot add an Index parameter to it.